# How to read the text data using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

My data is in the text file and the data format is shown below. The numericals are classes and the text is my feature. The first line i.e; 5485 is the total number of lines. I want to separate class and features ignoring the first line i.e; 5485. How to do it using pandas? Please help me.

5485

1 champion products ch approves stock split champion products inc said its board of directors approved a two for one stock split of its common shares

2 computer terminal systems cpml completes sale computer terminal systems inc said it has completed the sale of shares of its common stock and

1 cobanco inc cbco year net shr cts vs dlrs net vs assets mln vs mln deposits mln vs mln loans mln vs mln note th qtr not available year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameters `sep='|'` for one column `Dataframe` (need separator value which is not in data) with `skiprows` for omit first row:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, names=['data'], sep='|', skiprows=1)
print (df)
                                                data
0  1 champion products ch approves stock split ch...
1  2 computer terminal systems cpml completes sal...
2  1 cobanco inc cbco year net shr cts vs dlrs ne...
```

Then [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) column to both by first whitespace:

```
df[['class','features']] = df.pop('data').str.split(n=1, expand=True)
#convert column to numeric
df['class'] = df['class'].astype(int)
print (df)
  class                                           features
0     1  champion products ch approves stock split cham...
1     2  computer terminal systems cpml completes sale ...
2     1  cobanco inc cbco year net shr cts vs dlrs net ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
train = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv", header=0,delimiter=",", quoting=1)
num_reviews = train["columnTitleName"].size
for i in xrange(0, num_reviews): 
    dis =  train["columnTitleName"][i]
    print dis
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to include some description on how this answer help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).